# How to grant a full read only Azure AD role to a user?

Tags: azure, entra-id

I would like to grant someone a full read only access to all resources for an Azure subscription. I've reviewed the built-in roles and nothing fits the bill - e.g. security reader comes close but can't get a list of virtual networks or machines for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builtin roles are for basic pre-define setup, if none of them fits the 'bill', create you own custom role.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles

Comment: Are there any common role repositories online that are useful? My use-case (full r/o) seems like a common one.

Comment: Well from your description i assume the 'Reader' role on the subscription level would work.  That will give you read only access to all resource but you said you have already reviewed it so i am not sure what else. Sorry.